# Failed to fetch postgresql problem on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, postgresql, cmd

I am having a problem fetching data from postgresql repository. I have already uninstalled this one. But it keeps showing when I issued a "sudo apt-get update" command.

[image: Failed to fetch]

Answer (score 0):

try to continue with `apt-get install postgresql` since old files may have been used... If installation does not work, then consider adding another repository... a different one. I had a similar problem with mysql. You can also see that it does not find the page right? 404 page not found. Hope this helps you.